# KDE desktop program sees other content in /usr/bin than user sees in terminal - why?

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I would like to execute a program placed in **/usr/bin**.
From a terminal I can use it just by typing the name as it is in the path variable.
In a terminal also I can see it using **ls /usr/bin**.
The rights of the program file are: *-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root*

Now I have a KDE program I start via the desktop. Executing **ls /usr/bin** from this program shows different content and the desired program is missing, but other programs are there.

Why is that and how can I solve that?

Comment: hi, interesting, what if you `ls` the full path, is it found?

Comment: Thx, tried "ls /usr/bin/r -l". From the desktop program: No such file or directory.